# Makefile's 'vpath' doesn't work when searching prerequisites with wildcards

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

My project includes .c and .s (asm) files. I compile both types with 'gcc' and put output .o files to separate directory './bin'. To do that I'm using single makefile rule like this

```
bin/%.o: %.[cs]
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<
```

(As far as I understand, using square brackets wildcard in such context is a little bit unconventional, but it's working and it looks neat, so...)

The other day I decided to move some of my .c files to dedicated directory './common', so I added

```
vpath %.c common
```

at the beginning of the makefile. And now each time I try to 'make', it stops and throws an error on a file I had moved. For example, for 'common/foo.c' I get

```
"*** No rule to make target bin/foo.o, needed by..."
```

as if I haven't specified 'vpath'. But when I modify the rule to compile only .c files

```
bin/%.o: %.c
        ... ...
```

magically it starts to operate properly again and checks './common' for sources.

Looks like 'vpath' mechanism and wildcards can not work together, but I'm still new to 'make' and eager to learn what's the exact reason of such behavior. Any ideas anyone? Thanks in advance.

(Tested with make–3.81 and make–4.1.)

---

UPD: Having all the files and 'bin' directory reside on the same level like so

```
|-bin/
|-foo.c
|-bar.s
|-baz.c
|-Makefile
```

here's MWE

```
ROOTS   = foo.o bar.o
OBJS    = baz.o
SS      = $(addprefix bin/,$(ROOTS) $(OBJS))

all: ff.out

ff.out: $(SS)
    ld -o $@ $^

bin/%.o: %.[cs]
    gcc -o $@ -c $<
```

Now if I move, say, 'foo.c' to separate directory and specify 'vpath', build stops with "No rule to make target bin/foo.o, needed by ff.out".

Comment: Post a [mcve] of your original makefile, make assigns no special meaning to square brackets so it must have been using its built-in rules, but something doesn't add up about your description of the behaviour.

Comment: @user657267 Well, 'make' spec/4.3 tells otherwise: square brackets are treated as wildcard in a bash-like manner. I've added MWE to my question.

Comment: Sorry you're right, I can't believe I didn't know that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest careful reading of [How Not to Use VPATH](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/how-not-to-use-vpath/) as you seem to be at Step Three of that by having the OBJDIR in some places but not others.

To be explict, using a static pattern rule doesn't get you away from needing either at least one rule per source directory, or at least one `make` invocation per source directory. So, the simple answer is add a new rule for the new `common/` directory that's the same as the other one:

```
bin/%.o: common/%.[cs]
    gcc -o $@ -c $<
```

There are lots of more comprehensive, but complex, answers, see the followon article for some of them.

For simple projects, there is no reason not to just track what directories you have in your main Makefile by adding extra rules. Also, there's a reasonable case for not having that `bin/` dir and splitting `.o`  and `.out` locations. Distributors and others expect to be able to control where files are created running from a seperate directory anyway.

I've thrown up a [git repo with branches](https://code.launchpad.net/~gz/+git/soq43786731) based on your cut down example that may clarify things.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! In fact, I read the article you suggested before, but it didn't help me a lot and your second option is not working for me. Now I'm starting to think I have to reject the idea of using 'vpath' and specify all source paths directly.

What really baffles me though is that I can not find any examples of Makefiles, where wildcards like '?' or '[...]' are used. Strange.

Comment: You should just specify srcdirs directly, I've updated my answer to make that clearer. You may not see wildcards much because explictly listing files is prefered, or make-making tools of other kinds.